# Django Contact Emails Not Working

Tags: django, email

I have a contact form on my Django site and when submitted it goes to the success url but the email is not sent, and the logging set up in the form_valid function is never called.

Here is the code for the view:

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "contact.html"
    success_url = "/contact-sent/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        message = "{name} / {email} said: ".format(
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'),
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        message += "\n\n{0}".format(form.cleaned_data.get('message'))
        recipients = [recipient for recipient in settings.LIST_OF_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS]
        try:
            send_mail(
            subject=form.cleaned_data.get('subject').strip(),
            message=message,
            from_email='XXX@XXX.com'
            recipient_list=recipients,
            )
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.info("Contact Email sent successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.warning("Contact Email failed to send\nInfo: %s" % e)

        return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and the form, which is a model form using floppyforms and crispyforms:

```
class ContactForm(ffuture.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-contactForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'contact-form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit-feedback'
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                _('Contact Us'),
                Field('name', placeholder=_('Name'), css_class='input-medium'),
                Field('email', placeholder=_('Email'), css_class='input-xlarge'),
                Field('subject', placeholder=_('Subject'), css_class='input-xlarge'),
                Field('message', placeholder=_('Add a message'), rows='5', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            ),
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', _('Submit')))

    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message')
```

and the model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Feedback(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Feedback")
        verbose_name = _("Feedback")
```

The emails are never sent, and the Feedback model is never updated in the admin.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this would be happening?  I've been pouring over the code and looking at other examples and none of them seem much different from what I have.  I am stumped as to why it is not sending the emails, nor calling any of the logging in the form_valid method.

Ideally I want it to send the contact email to the recipients, and also save the information entered into the Feedback model.

Two other things that may be relevant:

The site is currently running on Apache and for the from_email set in the view I never configured any credentials for it.  I am unsure of where to do this.  But even if that's the reason the email is not being sent, I don't see why the Feedback model would not be updated.

Thanks for any help you guys can provide, I've been stuck on this for a bit now.

EDIT:

I was thinking it could be the send_mail function that is the issue, but I added logging above the try block and that wasn't called either, so I am now sure that the form_valid method is never being called.

As for the Feedback model not being saved, I realized this is probably because I am never actually saving the form.

I am a bit confused here, because I am using a model form for the contact so the user submitting the form is not logged in.  The objective was to both send the email, and store the results in the database.  But I can't seem to figure out how I should go about saving the modelform without a valid user.

Would it be enough to just do

```
feedback = form.save()
```

inside my form_valid method in the ContactView?  Or do I want a save method inside my model form?

Comment: Check the indentation of the `form_valid` method. It looks ok in the question, but if you've got it wrong in the view, then the default implementation would be to immediately redirect to the success url. Your URL and template might explain what's going on, although if you're redirected to the correct success url, then they are probably ok.

Comment: Yeah I double checked it, the indentation is same as it is in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just call

```
form.save()
```

and store the model.  The user being logged in did not matter as the fields on the model don't reference a logged in user at all.